# Rails 3 application/octet-stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on an application where I use paperclip for uploading images, then the image is manipulated in a flash app and returned to my application using application/octet-stream. The problem is that the parameters from flash are not available using params. I have seen examples where something like

```
File.open(..,..) {|f| f.write(request.body) }
```

but when I do this, the file is damaged some how.

How can I handle this in rails 3?

Comment: How are the parameters shown in your log, when the flash communicates with your application? Does the flash just modify some parameter of your form?

Comment: i can see something like id=1&png=... it looks ok, but params[:png] is empty

Comment: Is that in webserver's log or in the Rails' server log?

Comment: webserver log - I saw this in firebug (or some other http monitor, I dont remember)

Comment: I used http fox to monitor this, when I watch look at the post data I can see the parameters as I would expect, but the params[] is empty

Comment: First make sure whether your Rails server received the parameters. Check the file `log/development.log`. Compare this to webserver log (/var/log/apache/accept_log or something like this) - I suppose you do have some webserver between Rails and the browser. If Rails received the params, and in your action you don't see it, then maybe you have overwritten the method somehow? Just guessing. Be sure to check the webserver logs for the errors. Maybe there is something like mod_security? I give examples from the Apache-world, but the same rules apply to any webserver you may have in front of Rails.

Comment: There is not much place in comments, so I will write further suggestions in the answer section.

Answer (score 2):

After you make sure that the request parameters have hit the Rails application, you may want to ensure that there were no parsing problems. Try to add these lines in you controller's action:

```
def update # (or whatever)
  logger.debug "params: #{params.inspect}"
  # I hope you do not test this using very large files ;)
  logger.debug "request.raw_post: #{request.raw_post.inspect}"
  # ...
end
```

Maybe the variable names got changed somehow? Maybe something escaped the parameter string one time too much?

Also, you have said that the file into which you want to save the `request body` is damaged. How exactly?

The request.body object does not need to be String. It may be a StringIO, for example, so you may want to type this:

```
File.open(..,..) {|f| f.write(request.body.read) }
```